# Convert from a LPCTSTR to a wchar*

Tags: visual-c++

I have a c++ application, and i need to convert a LPCTSTR to a wchar*.

Is there function to perform this conversion?

Using Visual Studio 2k8.

Thank you

Comment: How you do this depends on what `LPCTSTR` is. Why are you still using `TCHAR`? Are you really still supporting Windows 98?

Comment: If you're building in Unicode mode then it probably already is. If you're not, your best option depends on which libraries you've got in your solution if anyy (e.g. ATL or MFC) but there's always MultiByteToWideChar.

Comment: LPCTSTR contains a null terminated wide string.  I do not see TCHAR anywhere in my question.  It is a legacy application - i have not control over the application.

Comment: The T in LPCTSTR means it's TCHAR-based. (LP = long/far pointer, C = constant, STR = string)

Comment: ... unless you're in QT-land and you're compiling with the flag that means wchar_t is a distinct C++ type from unsigned short. But hopefully you're not.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, you are compiling for Unicode. In which case `LPCTSTR` evaluates as `const wchar_t*` and so no conversion is necessary. If you need a modifiable buffer, then you can allocate one and perform a memory copy. That works because the string is already encoded in `UTF-16`.

Since you are using C++ it makes sense to store strings in string classes rather than using raw C strings. For example you could use [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Or your could use the [MFC/ATL string classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda99ffc.aspx). Exactly which of these options is best for you depends on the specifics of the rest of your code base.

Comment: nothing in his question or comments say he is compiling unicode. Also const wchar_t* is not the same a wchar_t*

Comment: @pm100 The comments say: *LPCTSTR contains a null terminated wide string.* It is of course true that `const wchar_t*` is different from `wchar_t*`. Nowhere do I say that those types are the same.

Answer (score 0):

LPCTSTR may either be multibyte or Unicode, determined at compile-time. WinNT.h defines it as follows

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef LPCWSTR LPCTSTR;
#else
    typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR
#endif
```

meaning that it is already composed of `wchar` as Rup points out in a comment. So you might want to check UNICODE and use `MultiByteToWideChar()` if undefined. Of course, you'd need to know the code page the string is using, which depends on where and how it originates. The [MultiByteToWideChar documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has good code samples.