# How to convert LPCSTR to WCHAR*?

Tags: c++, string

How to convert LPCSTR to WCHAR* into a Unicode project, please ? I haven't found much on the net.

Comment: Before posting a question, you should search for similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [Convert from a LPCTSTR to a wchar*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705028/convert-from-a-lpctstr-to-a-wchar)

or

[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f65e93cc-0a0f-4180-a201-4e6e0feae9d7/cannot-convert-parameter-1-from-lpctstr-to-const-wchar-?forum=vclanguage)

Comment: This applies to a different type: `LPC T STR`. It therefore uses the wrong macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **NOT** including `AtlBase.h`or `AtlConv.h`headers,

```
#include <windows.h>

LPCSTR lpcszTemp = "Hello World" ;

int wchars_num =  MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , lpcszTemp  , -1, NULL , 0 );
WCHAR* wstr = new WCHAR[wchars_num];

MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , lpcszTemp  , -1, wstr , wchars_num );
// ...Other codes...
delete[] wstr;
```